# Azure DevOps check branch name for ( in a bash

Tags: bash, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to check a branch name for the `(` sign.  E.g. we have `$(Build.SourceBranch) =  "test(1)"`.
When I try to call my command
"`myCommand $(Build.SourceBranch)`"
it fails with something like

```
/agent/_work/_temp/653563be-e452-4f06-a7a8-276aad30c025.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

where line 12 is the line in the bash with myCommand.

It would be OK also to check in the bash that the branch name does not contain "`(`" but whenever I try to check it is failing with syntax error:

```
 echo "sourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
 echo $(Build.SourceBranch) | grep -i '('
```

will print in log:

```
command: test(1)
/agent/_work/_temp/653563be-e452-4f06-a7a8-276aad30c025.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

In my local bash the above grep command would just return the branch name.
Any ideas on how I could exit the bash without a syntax error in this case would be very helpful.

I not only tried echo, also

```
if [ $(Build.SourceBranch) == "test(1)"] then echo "test " fi
```

with syntax error, tried also to convert the "(" in the string to some other string but unfortunately failed.

Comment: No, you do not need to check the branch name.  You need to *quote* it properly in your scripts, so that its contents are not subject to (mis)interpretation by the shell.  Or if you're planning to apply some other kind of escaping protocol instead, then you can and should do so unconditionally, which again means that you do not need to check in advance.

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with Azure pipelines, but generally the best way to deal with values with weird characters in situations like this is to pass them as environment variables, and let bash expand those (in double-quotes), like `echo "sourceBranch: $BuildSourceBranchVariable"`

Answer (score 0):

I can run the bash with the following yaml.

The branch name is test(1).
The value of `$(Build.SourceBranch)` is `refs/heads/test(1)`.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- bash: |
     echo "sourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
     echo "$(Build.SourceBranch)" | grep -i '('

     if [[ "$(Build.SourceBranch)" == *"test(1)" ]]; then 
     echo "test " 
     fi

  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out a solution and use:

`--scmBranch  $(echo '$[variables['Build.SourceBranchName']]' | base64)`

Then I decode scmBranch in the programm started, when accessing the parameter.